# How to access PCollection from DB I/O connector in next step in Pipeline

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have written a small pipeline using Apache-beam.It uses beam-postgres as Input connector to create a PCollection from a DB table.
The code looks like following-

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from psycopg.rows import dict_row
from beam_postgres.io import ReadAllFromPostgres
def __trigger_bill_fetch_job(self):
        print("Triggering bill-fetch job")            
        pipeline = beam.Pipeline()   
       
        read_from_db = ReadAllFromPostgres(
            "host={host} dbname={dbName} user={user} password={password}",
            "SELECT * FROM comparison_bill_data_requests WHERE status='PENDING' AND bill_event_received=true and bill_detail_event_received=true",
            dict_row,
        )

        result = pipeline | "ReadPendingRecordsFromDB" >> read_from_db | "Print result" >> beam.Map(print)

        pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()          
        print("read_from_db done", read_from_db)
```

The output if `beam.Map(print)` is

```
{'id': '1', 'bill_id': 'bill-1', 'account_id': None, 'bill_event_received': True, 'bill_detail_event_received': True, 'status': 'PENDING', 'commodity_type': None, 'bill_start_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 6, 11, 52, 28, 78945), 'bill_end_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 6, 11, 52, 28, 78945), 'tenant_id': 'tenant-1', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 6, 11, 52, 28, 78945), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 6, 11, 53, 21, 300224)}
```

How can I parse this to an object? I want to pass this to next step in pipeline and want to access it's properties. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the result of your `print`, the `beam_postgres` package returns a `PCollection` of `Dict` in the input connector from `Postgres`.

You can invoke a function in the `beam.Map` and access to the fields of the current `Dict` in the `PCollection` :

```py
from typing import Dict

import apache_beam as beam
from beam_postgres.io import ReadAllFromPostgres
from psycopg.rows import dict_row

def __trigger_bill_fetch_job(self):
    print("Triggering bill-fetch job")
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline()

    read_from_db = ReadAllFromPostgres(
        "host={host} dbname={dbName} user={user} password={password}",
        "SELECT * FROM comparison_bill_data_requests WHERE status='PENDING' AND bill_event_received=true and bill_detail_event_received=true",
        dict_row,
    )

    result = pipeline | "ReadPendingRecordsFromDB" >> read_from_db | "Print result" >> beam.Map(to_fields)

    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
    print("read_from_db done", read_from_db)


def to_fields(row: Dict) -> Dict:
    field1 = row["field1"]
    field2 = row["field2"]

    return row
```

In this example, I invoked the `to_fields` method from the `beam.Map` operator.
In this method, we have access to the current element in the `PCollection` that is a `Dict`, get the needed fields and apply a transformations in the result.

Comment: The function to_fields is not inside a DoFn. But I believe since beam.Map internally uses it, beam would still be able to distribute it among different workers right?

Comment: Yes, right. 
Internally, the beam.Map uses a DoFn and distribute the data among workers.

Comment: If the issue was solved in your side, can you mark as the answer as solved please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
PCollection<Row> rows = pipeline
    .apply(JdbcIO.<Row>read()
        .withDataSourceConfiguration(DataSourceConfiguration.create(...)
            .withUrl("jdbc:database-url")
            .withUsername("username")
            .withPassword("password"))
        .withQuery("SELECT * FROM my_table")
        .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<Row>() {
            public Row mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
            // Implement the mapping logic
        }
    }));
```

// Now you can use the PCollection 'rows' in the next steps of your pipeline

Comment: Thanks. But this looks like Java code. My application is in Python and I am not able to find too many useful examples using Python on web